# SQL Server : how to get previous year data and create a row in output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a delivery table as below:

[image: Table]

I want the count of delivery age wise. Vehicles delivered in 2010 will be counted as age 0 in 2010, age 1 in 2011 and age 2 in 2012 and so on for the years.

[image: Desired output]

Please help me to know how to do this in SQL query. I am new to this forum so don't have permission to add images.

Comment: You should not be adding images even if you do have permission.  Please _delete_ those image links and instead include all table data as text.

Comment: Your input data and output data are not in sync. Please provide correct sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a delivery in each year, I see this as a `JOIN` and aggregation:

```
with years as (
      select distinct year(deliverydate) as yyyy
      from vehicle
     )
select y.yyyy, (y.yyyy - year(v.deliverydate)) as age , count(*)
from vehicle v join
     years y
     on y.yyyy >= year(v.deliverydate) 
group by y.yyyy, (y.yyyy - year(v.deliverydate))
order by y.yyyy, (y.yyyy - year(v.deliverydate));
```

If you don't have a delivery in each year, you can explicitly list them:

```
select y.yyyy, (y.yyyy - year(v.deliverydate)) as age , count(*)
from vehicle v join
     (values (2010), (2011), (2012), (2013)) y(yyyy)
     on y.yyyy >= year(v.deliverydate) 
group by y.yyyy, (y.yyyy - year(v.deliverydate))
order by y.yyyy, (y.yyyy - year(v.deliverydate));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e8bfdef97f4b32f9dd96484bcc9625d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2011/08/25', getdate()) AS DateDiff
```

This will give you the age of vehicle and use group by clause to get value base on years as desired

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to do this

```
select year(deliverydate)
       ,(year(deliverydate)-2010) as age_of_vehicle
       ,count(vehicleid)
  from table
group by year(deliverydate)
```

Comment: But this does not give output as desired - Vehicles delivered in 2010 will be counted as age 0 in 2010, age 1 in 2011 and age 2 in 2012 and so on for the years.

Comment: Can you share the expected output. And an explanation. In 2011 you have age of vehicle 0 count as 2. How's have you derived that number

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are better ways to do this (recursive cte), but the following also gives the correct result:

```
;with cte as
(
    select YEAR(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, DeliveryDate, 105), 23)) [Year], 0 Age
    from vehicle v
)

select * into #temp
from cte
union all
select t1.[Year]+ (t2.[Year] - t1.[Year]), (t2.[Year] - t1.[Year]) as Age
from cte t1
join (select distinct [Year], Age from cte) t2 on t2.[Year] > t1.[Year]

select [Year], Age AgeofVehicle, COUNT(1) Deliveries
from #temp
group by [Year], Age
order by [Year], Age
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=898b08fae1255915d1acd7bf3f9feb9a)**.